# What is this wooden sheet behind my drywall?

Tags: drywall

I bought a home recently which was built in 2004.

I installed a TV mount on a stud and I am now trying to run cable behind drywall, but when I cut through my drywall I found wood sheet behind my drywall. What is that for? Can I cut through that wood?

As shown in the picture, the TV is mounted on a stud and stud finder is also attached to that stud for reference. [image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Any idea if this is across the whole wall? What's behind the wall? If you tap at various locations, does it sound different? I see a couple of holes; how thick is the wood?

Comment: I don't think it's uncommon for structure design to include such panels to provide additional shear strength in strategic locations. One wall supporting my stairwell has same.

Comment: It looks like it is all across the wall. it is really thin wood sheet., may be 1/2-1".
But behind and above that wall there is a staircase. May be it is support for that.
Is it safe to cut across that support wall or should I avoid it?

Comment: If it is chipboard and between 1/2-1" thick then you should be able to screw the tv mount (depending on final weight) directly through the drywall into the chipboard. But as you have screwd it throughinto the stud work, it wont be going anywhere. When you make the hole in the chipboard make sure it is smaller than the drywall, it will make it easier to repair later as you have something to bond on to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s undoubtedly a shear wall to resist lateral loads, especially if you live in a “high wind” area or a seismically active area.

It could also be a reinforced wall for shelving.

Yes, you can cut through it, or cut openings in it, whether it’s a shear wall or not. I would not make an opening more than 1/4 the height of the wall and not more than square shaped...don’t make it a large rectangle. Also, I’d install framing members at the edge of the opening. (If it’s a load bearing wall, you’ll need to install a header.)